# Storing Image Dimensions in Global Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, papaparse

So using papa parse, I parse my file as a local CSV file. So when I print my updated objects to the console, I get the object to return with the changed values I have applied based on certain conditions. My problem is getting the image dimensions: Width and Height.

```
  var w;
    var h;
    let testString = "s2345232";
    if (/^[s]\d+$/.test(testString) == true) {
                    url = baseUrl + testString + suffix;
                    getMeta(url, function (width, height) {
                        w = width;
                        h = height; 
                        console.log(w, h); //works
                    });  
                }
    console.log(w, h); //doesn't work
    //Here is the function to retrieve the image data
    function getMeta(url, callback) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = url;
        img.addEventListener("load", function () {
            callback(this.naturalWidth, this.naturalHeight);
    });
 };
```

Comment: `getMeta` is asynchronous. `w` and `h` won't be available at that time.

Comment: Then is there any way you can show a way for it to work that isn't asynchronous?